# Firebase and googleplus integration in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, swift3, google-plus

I am creating an iOS app. I need to integrate Push notification and google plus sigin in my app.I have integrated both google plus and push notification .I used firebase for push notification. When integrating firebase for push notification, i got one "GoogleService-Info.plist" file. I have imported that file into my project. I have also got another "GoogleService-Info.plist" file when i integrating google plus. It is not possible to import two files with same name. Then what should i do? How can i integrate both google plus and fire base together?Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use the freshest one, or override it with new one because if you are using same project for both push notification and sign in then both plist will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

just use the file "GoogleService-Info.plist" from firebase. Actually, when you should not create a new project on google developer, you should connect the existing project in Firebase.